# Нестандартный вывод записей из таблицы

Tags: mysql

Доброго дня.

Заранее благодарен всем, кто сможет помочь:) Уже 2 неделю бьюсь над задачей. Буду благодарен за любую мысль:)
Есть таблица с записями вида

```
   day       id_work       count
20130326        1            2
20130327        1            4
20130328        1            2
20130329        1            0
20130330        1            2
20130331        1            3
20130401        1            2
20130402        1            2
20130403        1            1
```

Таких записей очень много. Примерная задача: надо найти варианты 4-дневных диапазонов, в которых count выше 0, т.е. нужен запрос, который вывел бы из данных данной таблицы такое:

```
  day1         day2         id_work
20130330     20130402          1
20130331     20130403          1
```

А при 3-дневном диапазоне такие варианты:

```
  day1         day2         id_work
20130326     20130328          1
20130330     20130401          1
20130331     20130402          1
20130401     20130403          1
```

Принцип работы запроса. Скажем нужны 3-дневные диапазоны.

Берет первую запись 20130326, смотрит - count больше 0, это 1 день диапазона. Далее берет следующую запись 20130327, смотрит - count больше 0. Это 2 день диапазона. Далее берет следующую запись 20130328, смотрит - count больше 0. Это 3 день диапазона. 3 дня есть, то выводим

```
20130326 20130327 1
```

Далее уже начинаем с записи 20130327. Берет первую запись 20130327, смотрит - count больше 0, это 1 день диапазона. Далее берет следующую запись 20130328, смотрит - count больше 0. Это 2 день диапазона. Далее берет следующую запись 20130329, смотрит - ага, count равен 0. Все это диапазон уже не нужно выводить.

Далее уже начинаем с записи 20130328. Берет первую запись 20130328, смотрит - count больше 0, это 1 день диапазона. Далее берет следующую запись 20130329, смотрит - ага, count равен 0. Это диапазон уже не нужно выводить.

И так далее. Тут без переменных и вложенных запросов никак. Уже весь мозг себе сломал)) Возможно ли организовать запрос, который бы сделал нужные выводы? Спасибо.

Comment: А даты у вас хранятся именно в таком формате yyyymmdd? И какой же тип поля, если это так?

Comment: IamS, было бы так легко))) Принцип работы запроса указан.
Deonis, да такой формат, тип поля int. Можно конечно использовать тип date, но будет ли он полезен при составлении запроса?

Comment: > будет ли он полезен при составлении запроса?

А как вы думаете? )) Если есть даты *30-ое марта* и **2-ое апреля**, представленные в таблице, как *int*: *20130330* и *20130402*, то будет ли удобно вычислить диапозон между этими датами?

Comment: Хорошо, допустим тип данных date ))

Comment: @nerik, сегментную группировку не так просто сделать. Если чуть позде будет свободное время, то постараюсь помочь с таким запросом, но на вашем месте, я бы делал такие вещи средствами PHP.

Comment: Deonis, Palmervan спасибо Вам, но на php я это и сам могу сделать) Дело в том, что этот запрос будет часть другого более сложного запроса) База сама должна выдать период и id_work, чтобы эти данные перешли в другой запрос. В этом то и вся загвоздка)

Answer (score 1):

Поле day должно быть датой конечно. На MS SQL запрос будет такой - для 4 дневных диапазонов:

```
SELECT t1.day, MAX(t2.day), t1.id_work
FROM table t1
    JOIN table t2 ON t2.day < (t1.day+4) AND t2.day >= t1.day AND t2.count > 0
GROUP BY t1.day, t1.id_work
HAVING COUNT(*) = 4
ORDER BY t1.day
```

Comment: Тут получается 2 таблицы t1 и t2. Но таблица же одна t1 ) Саму на себя таблицу же можно join сделать?
Попробую задумку осуществить, идея неплохая. Если заработает, то спасибо))

Comment: @renegator, Да, [похоже на правду](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e31ff/6/0). Только в MySQL надо сделать одну маленькую поправку:    SELECT t1.`day`, MAX(t2.`day`), t1.`id_work`    FROM `tbl` t1        JOIN `tbl` t2 ON t2.`day` < (t1.`day`+ INTERVAL 4 DAY)           AND t2.`day` >= t1.`day`           AND t2.`count` > 0    GROUP BY t1.`day`, t1.`id_work`    HAVING COUNT(*) = 4    ORDER BY t1.`day`

Comment: Спасибо тут выражают принятием ответа

Comment: Я пока наполняю базу и буду пробовать вариант)
Как-то не охота разбрасываться принятием ответа, не проверив их.
Как только будут результаты я сразу напишу сюда и конечно же приму ответ.

Comment: Результаты не очень получились, но за направление спасибо)